# Unparseable date: "1/29/2014 11:45:00 AM" - Android

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I have a problem with parsing the following date from string: "1/29/2014 11:45:00 AM"
I do it the following way:

```
String source = "1/29/2014 11:45:00 AM";
Date startDate;
String sdfPattern = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(sdfPattern, Locale.getDefault());
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/London"));
this.startDate = sdf.parse(source);
```

Interestingly, this works fine in a java project, but not in android. The error message I get:

```
01-15 15:36:46.950: W/System.err(2713): java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "1/29/2014 11:45:00 AM" (at offset 19)
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I guess the missing 0 before the 1 in the month is the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your format string specifies that you'll provide a two-digit month, but you're only providing "1".

I suspect you want:

```
String sdfPattern = "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa";
```

Additionally, the "AM/PM" designator is locale-sensitive (as are the date and time separators) . If you know that it will always use English, you should say so:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(sdfPattern, Locale.US);
```

Unless the data is actually *entered* by the user (or being formatted for the user) you should avoid `Locale.getDefault()`.

Comment: Though I agree with you , why this is not an issue in Java?

Comment: @Nambari: It could be a matter of it parsing leniently - or the locale issue raised in my edit.

Comment: I threw this in an android project and it worked w/o problems.  I'm using API version 14

Comment: I tried with a single M, and changed locale to US... it still does not work. I am guessing, "offset 19" is hinting on AM/PM. But I am not sure

Comment: It was because of `Locale`, I changed the Locale to `Locale.US` but the rest remained the same. However, it was a little complicated in my code, that I used many of SimpleDateFormat's and it took some time for me to figure it out. Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 1):

Your default locale may not match the AM/PM marker in the input `String` causing the exception. Try using

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(sdfPattern, Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 0):

## java.time

The Question and other Answers use the troublesome old legacy date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java. Now supplanted by the java.time classes.

### ISO 8601

By the way, use the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats when generating Strings to represent date-time values for exchange with other software. Your format is ambiguous and trickier to parse, unlike the standard formats.

### `DateTimeFormatter`

The codes defining a formatting pattern in `java.time.DateTimeFormatter` are similar to the outmoded `SimpleDateFormat` but not exactly. So read the doc carefully.

```
String input = "1/29/2014 11:45:00 AM";

Locale locale = Locale.ENGLISH;  // For translating the “AM” & “PM”.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "M/d/uuuu hh:mm:ss a" ).withLocale( locale );
```

### `LocalDateTime`

Your input lacks any indication of an offset-from-UTC or a time zone. So we parse as a `LocalDateTime` object.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse ( input , f );
```

> ldt.toString(): 2014-01-29T11:45

A `LocalDateTime` object purposely lacks any [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) or time zone. That means it does *not* represent a moment on the timeline, only a rough idea about possible moments. You must assign an offset or time zone to give it meaning.

### `OffsetDateTime`

If the context of your suggestions indicates this input was meant to be in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time), apply the constant `ZoneOffset.UTC` to get an `OffsetDateTime`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset ( ZoneOffset.UTC );
```

> odt.toString(): 2014-01-29T11:45Z

### `ZonedDateTime`

On the other hand, if the context indicates a specific time zone, apply a `ZoneId` to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). The Questions seems to indicate that the [`Europe/London`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/London) time zone is intended. Be aware that this time zone is *not* the same as [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of ( "Europe/London" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone ( z );
```

> zdt.toString(): 2014-01-29T11:45-05:00[America/Montreal]

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (see [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706)).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.